# System.Data.DataTable - sort in alphabetical order

Tags: vb.net

I've got this code which populates a `SharpLibrary.WinControls.ListBoxEx`

```
Dim MyListBox As SharpLibrary.WinControls.ListBoxEx
Private dataTable As System.Data.DataTable
dataTable  = GetNames ' Function that returns a DataTable
MyListBox.Items.Clear()
 For count = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
    MyListBox.Items.Add(dataTable.Rows(count)("Name"))
Next
```

SharpLibrary is apparently some ancient graphical component API. 
I want the data to be presented in alphabetical order. Is it possible to sort a `DataTable`?

Edit: Another Solution:

```
dataTable  = GetNames ' Function that returns a DataTable
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Name"
MyListBox.Items.Clear()
 For count = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
    MyListBox.Items.Add(dataTable.DefaultView.Item(count)("Name"))
Next
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tags in your post? This doesn't seem VBA related...

Comment: Is `System.Data.DataTable` not Visual Basic? Maybe vb.net?

Comment: Most definitely VB.NET. ;)

Comment: You have a few options here. Are you using .NET 3.5 or above? If yes then you might want to use LINQ. If not you'll likely use the Select method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b5c0xc84(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to sort the values in the datatable before you add the items to the listbox.

Assuming you have Linq available in your project its pretty simple.

```
Dim MyListBox As SharpLibrary.WinControls.ListBoxEx
Private dataTable As System.Data.DataTable
dataTable  = GetNames ' Function that returns a DataTable
Dim temp = From r In dataTable Order By r.item("Name") select r
MyListBox.Items.Clear()
If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Any Then
    For count = 0 To temp.Count - 1
        MyListBox.Items.Add(temp(count)("Name"))
    Next
End If
```

This would be even easier if you were using a strongly typed datatable that is part of a dataset but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: That's what I would have suggested. This requires .NET 3.5 and above, though.

Answer (score 0):

This link is likely to help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73kk32zz(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:

```
  Dim view As DataView = table.DefaultView
view.Sort = "LastName, FirstName"
view.RowFilter = "LastName > 'M'"
PrintTableOrView(view, "Current Values in View")

' Create a new DataTable based on the DataView,
' requesting only two columns with distinct values
' in the columns.
Dim newTable As DataTable = view.ToTable("UniqueLastNames", True, "FirstName", "LastName")
```

This is the part where I believe it was done in the code.

I don't really know VB but its not too hard because the C# code is right underneath, I figure they ought to be really similar in meaning.

Comment: It's possible to have sorted data rows without using DataView, using the Select method. If it's .NET 3.5 or above it's also possible to use LINQ to achieve the same result.

Comment: Did not know that, I will edit the answer to reflect. Thanks.

Comment: You also don't want to create a copy of the table, especially if the sole purpose of having sorted rows is to populate a combobox. This isn't efficient usage of memory. Try working with the row instances you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DataView` for this.

```
Dim datav As New DataView
datav = dt.DefaultView
datav.Sort = "ColumnName DESC"
```

where `dt` = datatable that you get from `getNames()`.

finally, do this to convert it again to datatable datatype.

```
dt = datav.ToTable()
```

Final code is

```
Dim datav As New DataView
datav = dt.DefaultView
datav.Sort = "ColumnName DESC" 'or ASC, or anything just search for dataview.
dt = datav.ToTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = ColumnName & " ASC"
```